# How is a PDF supposed to be encoded?

Tags: pdf, groovy, character-encoding, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm trying to set up an API that generate PDF from web page (provided as URL). The API is gotenberg from thecodingmachine. I have it on Docker, it works just fine, I can't generate PDF through http request send with curl (for now I'm just trying to make it work, so I use the request provided as example in the documentation)

Now I am trying to make it work with my groovy/grails app. So I'm using the java tools to make the request.

Now here is my problem : the PDF file I get is blank (my app opend directly in my browser). It do has the right content, if I open it with the text editor, it's not empty, and it has almost the same content as the one I make using the curl request (which isn't blank).

I am 99% sure the problem come from the encoding. I tried changing the InputStreamReader encoding parameter, but it doesn't change anything. Here I put "X-MACROMAN" because that the encoding inside the pdf file that isn't blank, but it still doesn't change.

Here is my code :

```
static def execute(def apiURL)
{
        def httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()

        // Request parameters and other properties.
        def request = new HttpPost(apiURL)

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        builder.addTextBody("remoteURL", 'https://google.com')
        builder.addTextBody("marginTop", '0')
        builder.addTextBody("marginBottom", '0')
        builder.addTextBody("marginLeft", '0')
        builder.addTextBody("marginRight", '0')


        HttpEntity multipart = builder.build()
        request.setEntity(multipart)
        def response = httpClient.execute(request)

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "X-MACROMAN"))

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer()
        String line = ""

        Boolean a = Boolean.FALSE
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!a){
                a = Boolean.TRUE
            }
            else {
                result.append("\n")
            }

            result.append(line)

        }

        return result
```

I am 99% sure the problem come from the encoding. I tried changing the InputStreamReader encoding parameter, but it doesn't change anything. Here I put "X-MACROMAN" because that the encoding inside the pdf file that isn't blank, but it still doesn't change.

Did I made myself clear ? And does those who understands has any ideas why my PDFs are blank ?

Comment: are you trying to read pdf into a string? what's the purpose of this code?

Comment: Well yes, I do get it in a string, that I can display in my browser. The final purpose will be to convert it to base64 to send it to another API

Comment: No need to convert it into a string. Better to read it into ByteArrayOutputStream or redirect InputStream directly into the grails response (for your browser).

Comment: Not only is there "no need" to convert to a string, that conversion damages the PDF, so it's more a you "must not" convert to s string.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that. I used a string buffer because it was use somewhere else in the code and work just fine. I am currently trying to read it with a ByteArrayInputStream

Comment: Well it work, thanks guys